# Unable to use display math inside starred enumerate: Missing $ inserted / Bad math environment delimiter

Tags: math-mode, errors, enumerate, enumitem, starred-version

Trying to use display math `\[ \]` inside a starred `enumerate*` environment gives an error

> Bad math environment delimiter

or

> Missing $ inserted.

I can imagine this is by design, and that the idea is that `enumerate*` should only contain inline material. But I like `\[ \]` inside `enumerate*`; Is there any way to do this?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate*}
  \item Text \[ 0 = 1 \]   % Bad math environment delimiter
  \item Text \[ 0_1 \]   % Missing $ inserted.
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might need `\begin{enumerate*}[mode=unboxed]`.

Comment: `enumerate*` is designed  for inline lists, hence` indeed inline maths formulæ, just like  the `inparenum` environment from package `paralist`. Display maths equation are nonsense in this context. What would be the difference with a normal `enumerate` environment?

Comment: @campa That works, you can write an answer (even if perhaps you think it may not be an ideal solution).

Comment: @campa: Please write up an answer to get this question of the list of unanswered posts!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ups, sorry, I've been off the radar for a while... I'll do soon, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Bernard I believe I wanted an inline list for a proof with multiple items, where some items are very short. E.g. if the proof of one item is "Trivial." I liked the compact style without all the whitespace, and at the same time I needed display math somewhere.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Actually, I have no idea how I worked out that. I believe it was a wild guess based on the documentation, which, however, does not mention math explicitly. I think I did not write an answer because I did not know exactly what the reason was. And I'm still not comfortable with writing answers whose reasons are unclear to me. Maybe I should post a community wiki answer and hope someone will improve it?

Comment: @campa: Well, it's up to you of course. Either write the CW answer or use some time to remember how you found out in the past -- there's no need to hurry ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments and the `enumitem` documentation says, you need to pass the option `mode=unboxed` in such situations.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Some outer text for context.
\begin{enumerate*}[mode=unboxed]
  \item Item without display math,
\item text \[ 0 = 1, \] which is rarely true,
\item text \[ 0_1, \] might be needed,
\item item without display math.
\end{enumerate*}
We then continue.

\end{document}
```